# Does a db.RunInTransaction always require a way to check or handle a rollback?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

The application I have taken over has this code:

```
   db.RunInTransaction(() =>
   {
      foreach (CategorySource category in categories)
      {
         db.Insert(category);
      }
      Console.Out.WriteLine("Categories: \r\n {0}", categories.Count);
   }); db.Commit();
```

Can anyone tell me what is the benefit to running this in a transaction if there is no way to handle or check if there was a rollback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the example you showed us, namely doing a single insert, I don't see any benefit from doing it inside a transaction if there is no possibility to catch an exception and rollback.  However, more likely the intention was to make a simple way to execute *multiple* SQL commands, e.g. multiple inserts, inside a single transaction.  There would be a point of using a transaction there, if your code wanted those inserts to be made atomically from the point of view of other observers of your database.  This holds true even if there is no chance for rollback, provided that you are reasonably certain/unconcerned that a failure might not happen.

From the [sqlite-net documentation](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/wiki/Transactions), there is a way to do a rollback, but you need to use the low level API, e.g.

```
db.BeginTransaction ();
try {
    foreach (CategorySource category in categories)
    {
        db.Insert(category);
    }
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Categories: \r\n {0}", categories.Count);
    db.Commit ();
}
catch (Exception) {
    db.Rollback ();
    throw;
}
```