# Room database transaction rollback

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

With Room Database, I'm executing multiple `DELETE` + `INSERT` queries from different `DAO's`.

I'm using transactions as:

```
myDb.runInTransaction(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
     }
});
```

Is there a way to `ROLLBACK` in case anything fails?

**Later edit:**
Using this pattern seems to work:

```
myDb.beginTransaction();
if(success){
 myDb.setTransactionSuccessful(); -> commit
}
myDb.endTransaction();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a db.RunInTransaction always require a way to check or handle a rollback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41009327/does-a-db-runintransaction-always-require-a-way-to-check-or-handle-a-rollback)

Comment: I apparently answered a very similar question.  If you have multiple statements, then there is a way to rollback, but you need to use a different pattern.

Comment: My question was about Room Persistence Library. But indeed, using a different pattern for transactions seems to solve this. myDb.beginTransaction(); then if transaction succeeds, run myDb.setTransactionSuccessful();  at the end run myDb.endTransaction();

Comment: How do u determine isSuccess , you will read the output of each query in the transaction? @AlexBusuioc

Answer (score 2):

The transaction will not be set as successful if an exception occurs, meaning it will be rolled back at the end of the transaction. This is the [code for `runInTransaction()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/room/runtime/src/main/java/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.java#241):

```
public void runInTransaction(Runnable body) {
    beginTransaction();
    try {
        body.run();
        setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
        endTransaction();
    }
}
```

So, you can create something along the lines of:

```
try {
    myDb.runInTransaction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // DELETE
            if (failed) {
                throw new Exception("failed"); // ROLLBACK
            }
            // INSERT
        }
    });
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // Error handling
}
```

As the `Runnable` code is invoked synchronously.

And, if code uses lambdas instead of a `Runnable` anonymous class it will look cleaner. :)

Comment: Can you throw an exception from inside run() of Runnable?

Comment: Yes. Notice that in this case `Runnable` is not inside a `Thread` (which is a common case). So, it's run synchronously, that's why you can catch the `Exception`.

Comment: I seem to be missing something. I cannot compile if I pass a Runnable that throws something, but I can compile if I pass a Callable

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana if ->"failed", what does failed here refer to? An exception or the result returned from executing the query? If I catch the exception and rethrow again for the UI to reflect an error occurred, then will the transaction still be rolled back ?

Comment: Hi @user12865. By failed I meant any condition that you may need (a result returned from the query might do). In the case of an exception, you can catch it if you need to do some handling before rethrowing it (eg. clean up something, or even logging the exception for debugging purposes). You don't really need to catch and rethrow if that's the only thing you will do, as the original exception will already rollback the transaction if it's not cached.

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana thanks for clearing the confusion

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana: could you also please give an example of returning values using Callable instead of Runnable? Like how we could return a result object or an error if an exception occurred? I just posted a query regarding the same . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58038053/returning-value-from-runintransaction-in-android-room-database

Comment: @user12865 I've replied to your new question. Let's follow up the discussion there.

Answer (score 1):

Hope my answer helps you because I don't know anything else about the method you want to do.

From the Android Developer Docs.

```
 @Dao
public abstract class ProductDao{
    @Insert
     public abstract void insert(Product product);
     @Delete
     public abstract void delete(Product product);
     @Transaction
     public void insertAndDeleteInTransaction(Product newProduct, Product oldProduct) {
         // Anything inside this method runs in a single transaction.
         insert(newProduct);
         delete(oldProduct);
     } 
  }
```

You must use the @Transaction annotation in the method to indicate that all the changes made inside it will be wrapped in a transaction.

Comment: NO, thats wrong. Room does not manage transactions. It only makes sure that everything runs within one transaction. U need to manage error transactions by ur own