# Returning value from runInTransaction() In Android Room database

Tags: android, database, android-room, callable

There is not much documentation to understand how exactly does runInTransaction() method works. 
While executing multiple operations on different DAO's if no value is to be returned I could use `runInTransaction(Runnable body)` OR `runInTransaction(Callable<V> body)` if any result is to be returned.

**Query that I have:**
If all the queries in the transaction are successful, then I want to return an image object that needs to be uploaded to a server on successful transaction
If any exception occurred or the transaction was not successful I need to return a boolean with false to indicate the user that some error occurred.

**Here is the method:**

```
public boolean userCheckedIn(final User user) {
    try {
        appDatabase.runInTransaction(new Callable<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {
                if (user != null) {

                   //Add entry in table A
                     appDatabase.UserDao().add(user);

                   //Update entry in table B 

                   //Delete an entry from table C 

                    Event image = updateUserAction(action);
                    return image;
                }
                return null;
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In the above method, what I intend to do is, if all the database executions are a success I need to return an image which will be uploaded to the server. If there is any exception that occurred or any error occurred while doing the db transaction I need to return `false` to let user know an error occurred. Not sure if I got it right. Also, should I be putting the runInTransaction in try catch block ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code for `runInTransaction(Callable)` is equivalent to the `runInTransaction(Runnable)` version:

- if the transaction succeeds (this is, no exceptions are thrown) it sets the transaction as successful (by calling `setTransactionSuccessful()`, without this is considered failed and will be rolled back).
- ends the transaction in any case (at this point, if it was set as successful the whole transaction is committed, else is rolled back).
- if an exception is thrown inside the `Callable` or `Runnable`, the exception is not handled (in the `Callable` case it is, but is rethrown). This means you need to handle it in the code calling either `runInTransaction(Callable)` or `runInTransaction(Runnable)`.

The main functional difference is that `runInTransaction(Callable)` returns the value returned by the `Callable`.

So, your code can do two things:

- either return the image on success or `null` on failure, and upload the image in the method calling to `userCheckedIn(User)` or,
- upload the image inside your `userCheckedIn(User)` method

The second solution (easier for me to show you the code given I don't have the code for the method calling to `userCheckedIn(User)`) will look similar to this:

```
public boolean userCheckedIn(final User user) {
    try {
        Event image = appDatabase.runInTransaction(new Callable<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {
                if (user != null) {
                    //Add entry in table A
                    appDatabase.UserDao().add(user);

                    //Update entry in table B 

                    //Delete an entry from table C 

                    Event image = updateUserAction(action);
                    return image;
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
        if (image != null) {
            // Upload the image to the server
        } else {
            // No image available (probably because of the "if (user != null)"
            // inside Callable). I assume you want to return false in this case.
            return false;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way, just create a wrapper method:

```
fun <T> runInTransactionValue(
    database: GeneratedDatabase,
    run: Callable<T>,
): T {
    return database.runInTransaction(run)
}
```